# I need to put the date in a Write Range Workbook activity

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-activity

I need to put the date in a Write Range Workbook activity as the title of an excel sheet and save it so that it compares the table from a day before with the current one

I tried assigning now to a variable of type datetime and adding the variable with a .ToString, and I don't know how to make it save a new sheet and compare with a previous one so I can compare it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You have some images?